# Integration with respect to a discontinuous function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I know that a function is differentiable iff it follows the first theorem of differentiability
i.e.
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
so if a function is **discontinuous** at some points it is **non differentiable** there too.

For example:
**$$[x]$$**  it is discontinuous at integer value and non differentiable too.

So for the question let me take an example:

$$\int_{0}^4 x^2d[x]$$

This has the greatest integer function then how can we even integrate this in the first place.

Pease write it in details with the example and description why can we integrate it..

Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: This is what is called a Riemann-Stieltje's integral and you don't require continuity of $[x]$. You can look at Apostol's book for the definition.

Comment: Ookk seeing the book online .....checking the integral... thanks

Comment: You can consult for a start: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Stieltjes_integral`

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The man's name was **Thomas Johannes Stieltjes**, so do not use the possessive apostrophe like **Stieltje's**

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks...for the link....